# Why and when one should use IPC_NEW to create semaphore?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ipc, semaphore

we can create semaphore by two ways . 

1.

```
 static unsigned int state = 1 ;
 key_t h=ftok(".", state++);
 int sem_id=semget(h, no_of_sems, IPC_CREAT|0666);
```

and
 
 2.

```
 int sem_id =semget(IPC_NEW,no_of_sems,0666|IPC_CREAT);
```

As in Linux manual http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html mentioned that

**IPC_PRIVATE isn't a flag field but a key_t type.  If this special
       value is used for key, the system call ignores all but the least
       significant 9 bits of shmflg and creates a new shared memory segment.**

I am not getting what manual says . Can somebody explain more ? 
**What are pros and cons of using 1st method over 2nd method ?**

```
Edit:
IPC_PRIVATE => IPC_NEW
```

Comment: You might want to scroll down to the [BUGS section of the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html#BUGS).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg can you give an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

First up all you should observe the BUG

```
   The name choice IPC_PRIVATE was perhaps unfortunate, IPC_NEW would
   more clearly show its function.
```

ok.Just i explained  what i know about `shmget`

See the description for `shmget`

```
   int shmget(key_t key, size_t size, int shmflg);

DESCRIPTION
   shmget()  returns  the identifier of the System V shared memory segment
   associated with the value of the argument key. A  new  shared  memory
   segment,  with size equal to the value of size rounded up to a multiple
   of PAGE_SIZE, is created if key has the value IPC_PRIVATE or key  isn't
   IPC_PRIVATE,  no shared memory segment corresponding to key exists, and
   IPC_CREAT is specified in shmflg.
```

In `ipc.h` file `IPC_CREAT` is defined as macro like

```
 /* resource get request flags */
 #define IPC_CREAT  00001000   /* create if key is nonexistent */
 #define IPC_EXCL   00002000   /* fail if key exists */
 #define IPC_NOWAIT 00004000   /* return error on wait */
```

If IPC_CREAT is used alone, shmget() either returns the segment identifier for a newly created segment, or returns the identifier for a segment which exists with the same key value. If IPC_EXCL is used along with IPC_CREAT, then either a new segment is created, or if the segment exists, the call fails with -1. IPC_EXCL is useless by itself, but when combined with IPC_CREAT, it can be used as a facility to guarantee that no existing segment is opened for access.

A shared memory identifier and associated data structure and shared  memory segment of at least size bytes are created for key if one of the following are true:

```
   o  The key argument is equal to IPC_PRIVATE.

   o  The key argument does not already have a shared  memory
      identifier  associated  with it, and (shmflg&IPC_CREAT)
      is true.
```

Comment: You are correct you took all information . Why one should use 2nd option ?

Comment: IPC_CREAT:
If no semaphore set with the specified key exists, create a new set.

Comment: 1st method is also doing the same thing ?